# Is there a linear recurrence with infinitely many zeros, conjecturally infinitely many primes and non-zero terms of exponential growth?

Tags: nt.number-theory, integer-sequences

Let $a_n$ be a linear recurrence with integer constant coefficients
and initial values.

Is it possible $a_n$ to satisfy all of these:

1. $a_n = 0$ infinitely often.
2. if $a_n \ne 0$, $ | a_n |$ is of exponential growth
   (to avoid cases like $\dots 0 , n , 0 ,n+1, \dots$).
3. $ | a_n |$ is conjectured to be prime infinitely often.
   Since it is not known if there are infinitely many 
   Fibonacci primes, proving primality is hard, but
   there shouldn't be obvious obstructions like
   divisibility by a single prime or some polynomial
   factorization when treating a coefficient as a variable.

If this is possible, what is minimal order of $a_n$
(it can't be $2$)?

Comment: Related question today: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/147169/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.  $a_n=a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}-a_{n-3}+a_{n-4}-a_{n-5}$ has a solution containing zeros and Fibonacci numbers: $0,1,0,1,0,2,0,3,0,5,0,8\ldots$.

Comment: Thank you! According to OEIS this can be simplified to order 4: A079977. a(n) = a(n-2)+a(n-4). Do you think order 3 is possible?

Comment: I thought that was cheating.  No, I don't think order 3 is possible.  It doesn't work if every second or third term is 0, but we would need to rule out more occasional zeros.

Comment: Skolem-Lech-Mahler says you can't have (infinitely many) "occasional" zeros; they come in arithmetic progressions.